# Intellij IDE is holding models.jar not letting hybris to clean build

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

Latest version of intellij 15 is holding models.jar file which blocks Hybris tomcat to clean start the server. Attached screenshot for reference.

Does anyone know what is that i am missing?

Refer the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWXOt.jpg

Comment: Is your hybris application currently running? Try to shut the application down and run `ant clean all`

Comment: Thats not the case, earlier intellij would not lock any file. after recent upgrade of version 15. it locks the generated files(models.jar). `ant clean all` fails as it cannot delete the locked file. work around fix is to close Intellij IDE and run `ant clean all` which works fine. But i want to know why this behaviour after recent upgrade? is it a bug?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 15 myself too, but I can't replicate the problem. Maybe a clean install of intelliJ will solve the problem?

Comment: I think it may be Windows related problem. File locking problems usually occurs on MS Windows and can be related not only to IntelliJ. I'd suggest you to clean and start the app from the command line interface and use IntelliJ just for code editing and debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3):

if you are working with hybris, then it's plugin setup option:

```
Compiler->Hybris->"Enable model generation"
```

option, disable it

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following thing, 
1) I have deleted model.jar file using lockhunter

http://lockhunter.com/thanksforinstall.htm?ver=3.2.3.126&ostype=win64&sm=Congrats

2) then deleted hybris/temp folder using the same.

3) ant clean all (which was build successful)

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Edit configuration -> Remote choose Remote dubug, press OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main reason could be your hybris server is still running.
Stop it with `CTRL+C` in the command line or `hybrisserver.bat stop`

**In case your server is already stopped:**

> It's possible there is JVM process still running that holds this
>   model.jar file. Try to stop it from the Task Manger. `Ctrl+Shift+Esc -> End JVM task`.

Answer (score 0):

Its wired its happening with me too. I found a way, If you refresh project from Intellij menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).